# JavaFX Make WebEngine setUserStyleSheetLocation detect CSS file in a JAR

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, javafx-css

I'm trying to style a JavaFX [WebEngine](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) using the [setUserStyleSheetLocation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setUserStyleSheetLocation(java.lang.String)) method. The method's documentation says it requires a "local URL" starting with `data:`, `file:`, `jar:`, or `jrt:`. I want to package my project in a runnable JAR file, but I don't know where to put my `web.css` file nor what to pass into the `setUserStyleSheetLocation` method in order for my app to detect the CSS file at runtime.

My project structure is:

```
- OuterProjectFolder
  - src
    - pack
      - Main.java
    - resources
      - web.css
```

but I can move `web.css` if needed.

Given the above placement of `web.css`, I have tried passing all of the following literal strings to `setUserStyleSheetLocation`, to no avail:

```
file:web.css
jar:web.css
file:resources/web.css
jar:resources/web.css
file:/resources/web.css
jar:/resources/web.css
file:src/resources/web.css
jar:src/resources/web.css
```

and I have also tried passing:

```
Main.class.getResource("/resources/web.css").toString()
Main.class.getResource("/resources/web.css").toExternalForm()
```

To create my JAR, I am using Eclipse's `File > Export... > Runnable JAR File` with "Library handling" set to "Package required libraries into generated JAR." I have double-checked that the CSS file is actually in my JAR. My app is able to load other things from my `resources` folder such as images and even other CSS files (like the one used to style my `Scene`).

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried `Main.class.getResource("/resources/web.css").toString()`?

Comment: Also, this Q&A may help: [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other).

Comment: @Slaw When I use `Main.class.getResource("/resources/web.css").toString()`, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid stylesheet URL` from `WebEngine`. Calling`getResource(...).toString()` returns a string starting with `rsrc:`, which is not listed as one of the allowable prefixes in the docs for `setUserStyleSheetLocation`. Looking at the code called by `setUserStyleSheetLocation`, it seems that those prefixes (`data:`, `file:`, etc.) are literally enforced by a string comparsion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why they're so strict. But the `rsrc:` scheme is a consequence of how Eclipse packages runnable JARs with "package required libraries into generated JAR" enabled. In a "normal" JAR file, `getResource` would be giving you a `file:jar:` scheme.